# How can I file.find("a","b","c"..... etc. "z") and ord("A","B","C"..... etc. "Z") in python

Tags: python, find

Hi I can't find another question that answers this because it is really basic. I'm learning python and my current code will have to be copy and pasted for every letter of the alphabet. Instead how can I use `find()` and `ord()` for a range/A-Z.

This is my code at the moment:

```
A = (ord("A")-64)*(file.find("a"))
if A < 0:
    A = 0
B = (ord("B")-64)*(file.find("b"))
if B < 0:
    B = 0
C = (ord("C")-64)*(file.find("c"))
if C < 0:
    C = 0

print(A+B+C)
```

I want to do this all the way to Z but there must be a way to do that without copying and pasting.

If you can help, thank you so much. I've tried `file.find("a","b"...)` but this wouldn't work.

Comment: Have you thought about using some sort of loop?

Comment: from file count the occurrence of the a,b,c and multiple them by 1,2,3 respectively in order and add them, that's is your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the strings library or just decare the alphabets on your own

with String library:

```
import string
alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase
print(alphabets)
```

Outputs:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

And now you can loop over it:

```
for characters in alphabets:
    print(characters) # replace this with your code
```

Put your code instead of the print statement. Similarly for uppercase import uppercase from string instead of lowercase.

Comment: ```ord(characters)``` gave me a value of 90 when A should = 65, B = 66 and so on. Was this meant to sum all of them?

Comment: Can you paste the code?  and share the file as well.